# Spring boot ConfigurationProperties - Inject a TreeMap with a comparator

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the following config properties in a spring boot app:

```java
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "test")
public class ConfigProperties {

    private Map<String, String> values = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);

    public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
```

I want to end up with a Map that ignore the case of the keys.

When the injection occurs, the setValues method receives a treemap without the comparator.

I fixed this by changing the setter to this:

```java
    public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
        this.values.clear();
        this.values.putAll(values );
    }
```

Is there a proper way to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing everything correctly to copy all entries of one arbitrary map into a sorted `TreeMap` with a custom comparator. Basically you only have two options: clear and `putAll` or create a new instance and `putAll`

*But*, I don't think this should be something that the configuration is responsible for. Your intended order likely has some business value, depending its use. So ordering should happen in the code that uses the values of the configuration. But then again, see both options above.

Comment: This is more of a trick. I don't need it ordered, but really, a case insensitive map.

Comment: I use UPPERCASE keys in my code, like "map.get("SOMETHING")". I set the values using the properties file, like my.app.value[SOMETHING] and it works.
The issue comes when I need to define this values using system environment variables, like MY_APP_VALUE_SOMETHING, it ends up as lowercase when injected by spring.

Comment: I think the general advice still applies: this is not something the configuration should be responsible for, but one layer above in the "business" logic. Do you actually need the dynamic nature of the map, i.e. arbitrary keys, or do you only need to support a predefined set of keys? If so, consider defining a nested configuration class with a dedicated property for each key. This would also give you autocompletion in most IDEs